# Is there a shortcut to normalizing a table where the columns=rows?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-normalization, database-table

Suppose you had the mySQL table describing if you can mix two substances

```
Product   A    B    C
---------------------
A         y    n    y
B         n    y    y
C         y    y    y
```

The first step would be to transform it like

```
P1   P2   ?
-----------
A    A    y
A    B    n
A    C    y
B    A    y
B    B    y
B    C    n
C    A    y
C    B    n
C    C    y
```

But then you have duplicate information. (eg. If A can mix with B, then B can mix with A), so, you can remove several rows to get

```
P1   P2   ?
-----------
A    A    y
A    B    n
A    C    y
B    B    y
B    C    n
C    C    y
```

While the last step was pretty easy with a small table, doing it manually would take forever on a larger table. How would one go about automating the removal of rows with duplicate MEANING, but not identical content?

Thanks, I hope my question makes sense as I am still learning databases

Comment: `A A y`, `B B y` etc seem pretty obvious. Why don't you generate the table correctly, right from the start? Just take one of the triangles, excluding the diagonal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's safe to assume that you're starting with all relationships doubled up, e.g.

If `A B` is in the table, then `B A` is guaranteed to be in the table.

Then all you have to do is remove all rows where P2 < P1;

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `P2` < `P1`;
```

If this isn't the case, you can make it the case by going through the table and inserting all the duplicate rows if they don't already exist, then running this.

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer helpful - but I would recommend waiting longer for responses before accepting. It's quite possible that there's a much better solution than this, or there's a critical flaw in mine.

Comment: good answer -- as long as the assumption that all relationships are doubled holds true.  If you can't be sure the assumption will hold, though, you should check for duplicates before deleting.

Comment: All relationships are doubled, I generated the table with a nested for loop.

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's necessary in your situation, but as an intellectual exercise, you could build on Jamie Wong's solution and prevent non-duplicated columns from being removed with an EXISTS clause. Something like this:

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` AS t1
  WHERE `P2` < `P1`
    AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM `table_name` AS t2
      WHERE t1.`P1` = t2.`P2` AND t1.`P2` = t2.`P1`);
```

It pretty much just makes sure that there's a duplicate before deleting anything.

(My MySQL syntax might be a little off; it's been a while.)

Comment: good point.  If you use the delete approach, you should check for duplicates before deleting.  You can avoid deleting and the duplicate check altogether, though (see my answer above).

Comment: @dave Probably shouldn't say "above". Unless you're that certain it will receive more upvotes :P

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 (as you've already done): Transform to Table2

```
P1   P2   ?
-----------
A    A    y
A    B    n
A    C    y
B    A    y
B    B    y
B    C    n
C    A    y
C    B    n
C    C    y
```

Step 2: ReOrder Columns, Select Distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   IF P1<P2 THEN P1 ELSE P2 END as P1, -- this puts the smallest value in P1
   IF P1>P2 THEN P1 ELSE P2 END as P2 -- this puts the largest value in P2
FROM Table2
WHERE NOT P1=P2  --(Assuming records like A, A, y are not interesting)
```

I'm not a mySQL guy, so you might need to check the if/then syntax, but this seems conceptually ok anyway.

Comment: btw -- maybe this is just homework -- but as for a real-world concern -- you might consider mixtures with more than 2 parts.  E.g., it might be ok to mix A with B; and ok to mix B with C; but mixing all three A, B & C together might turn out to be something you'd want to avoid.